# В чём разница между picturebox.Invalidate(), picturebox.Refresh() и picturebox.Update()?

Tags: c#

Какой из методов использовать для рисования объектов в picturebox и их перемещения?

Comment: А какие из них вы проверили, какие работают, какие нет?

Comment: Все работают одинаково в моей ситуации

Comment: @ATG54 Насколько я понимаю правильно использовать `Invalidate` чтобы пометить обновлённые области и не торопить искусственно само обновление.

Comment: Самое смешное, что картинка рисуется даже без этих методов, хотя всё рисование у меня прописано в событии Paint

Answer (score 1):

Пояснение на [английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/8324991):

```cs
this.Invalidate();  // добавляет перерисовку области в очередь обновления
this.Update();      // вызывает перерисовку областей из очереди обновления 
this.Refresh();     // делает Invalidate() и сразу следом Update()
```

Обычно нужно просто вызывать `Invalidate`, отрисовка происходит сама с какой-то частотой. Если вас не устраивает стандартная отрисовка, тогда уже нужно думать.